# AngularJS mechanism to ask server for token based status

Tags: angularjs, html

In my client side I have a button that triggers an api call that take few minuts to reply, so in the server side I want to return a token to the client and and then the client can ask for status based on the token.

How the client can ask for status every 1 min lets say? and I also dont want to use database and just want to save the token in cache, how can I do that too?

thansk!

Comment: Search for `ngIdle` module. Thats what you need

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best or the only solution. But I have been using this library for a while and its good and simple.

[ngIdle](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-idle)  helps you track the time against your angular app and perform function as and when that time elapses. This is usually for a timeout and idle type of stuff but I suppose you too can use it.

Usage:

In your app's config, initialize the library as:

```
 function ConfigFn(IdleProvider) {

        //set configuration for ng-idle
        IdleProvider.idle(60); //in seconds
        IdleProvider.timeout(120); //do not use this if not really required
}
```

AFAIK, it provides you 2 time hooks and an event is raised at each time hook. You can listen to this event and perform any function.

In your `run` block :

```
function runtimeFn(Idle) {
        //setting a timer watch as soon as application bootstraps, you have to reset it every time your time elapses and you call server.
        Idle.watch(); //Idle is just a service from the library

        //responsing to various events in the application
        $rootScope.$on('IdleStart', callServerForToken);
        $rootScope.$on('IdleTimeout', doSomethingAgainIfYouWant); //do not use this if not really required
    }
```

This should help you. Let me know if something remains unclear.